# Javascript object creation using functions

Tags: javascript

```
var boxArea = function() {
    this.width=2;
};

alert(boxArea.width);
```

Good day. Why does this return an undefined value?

Comment: Read up the on javascript's [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth). It explains how your width variable is private to the boxArea object.

Comment: will work with "= new function"

Answer (score 3):

Because you created a function with that syntax. You have to add the "new" keyword in front of the function() to make it the equivalent of a class.

jsFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfUQu/

```
var boxArea = new function() {
    this.width=2;
};

alert(boxArea.width);​
```

Comment: okay so the new keyword makes a new object. but isn't it that functions are also object?

Comment: They are similar in syntax but designed for different purposes. A function is just meant to be called in order to perform some work. Once it exits anything defined inside is now out of scope and discarded. A class is meant to be *instantiated* and *reused*. The *new* keyword creates an *instance* of any user defined (or build in object, like Date() for example).

Comment: Can I say that var person = {}; is same as var person=new object();

Comment: Yes, that is called "object literal" syntax.

Comment: and what is the equivalent syntax for "new function()"?

Comment: In object literal? var boxArea = { width: 2 };

Comment: how about in terms of function?

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to create a javascript constructor is using a declared function:

```
function BoxArea(width) {
  this.width = width;
}
```

By convention, constructors have names starting with a capital letter. Then you create an instance:

```
var ba = new BoxArea(2);

alert(ba.width); // 2
```

For such a simple object you could just do:

```
var ba = {width: 2};
```